# CLI command to register child module into parent module not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using a CLI command to register child module into parent module using a CLI is not working.

I ran the code below -

`ng g m shared/shared --flat -m products/product.module`

I see the new module(shared) getting created but its not getting registered in the parent component(product.module)

CLI outputs this -

`CREATE src/app/shared/shared.module.ts (190 bytes)`

But its not doing the `UPDATE` on `product.module`

Am i missing anything in the CLI command?

Comment: Try removing the last ".module" part like this: `ng g m shared/shared --flat -m products/product`

Comment: Nope it dint work.

Comment: Can you share your folder structure and Angular CLI version?